# Folder colors in juno

Tags: pantheon-files, folder, color

after 5 years of honored service, I am replacing Freya with the new Juno on my main (server) machine.

I see that the pantheon-files folder color has been changed from the old delicious light blue to this ugly yellow.

Is it possible to restore the old folder color in pantheon-files?

Best
Pietro

Comment: I think the reason for this change was to be reminiscent of manilla folders and also to allow for the future use of different colored icons for special folders.  I do not know of a way to change the color except, possibly by changing the icon theme (not recommended).

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your answer. Let's hope that it will be possible to color folder icons soon! Although I'll miss the old icon system!